# When using .each in jQuery with a JSON object how do I avoid undefined properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm attempting to fill the values of `<inputs>` on a page using the data from a JSON object.

http://codepen.io/jimmykup/pen/exAip?editors=101

First I create my JSON object. In this case it only has two values. One `name` and one `url`.

```
var jsonObj = [];

var name = "1stname";
var url = "firsturl";

item = {}
item ["name"] = name;
item ["url"] = url;

jsonObj.push(item);
```

Next I use jQuery's .each() to find all inputs with a class of `.name` and I use the `index` to insert the value of "name" into the input. After that I want to go through all of the inputs with `.url` as the class name and do the same.

```
$("input.name").each(function( index ) {
    if ( jsonObj[index].name ) {
      $(this).val( jsonObj[index].name );
  }
});

$("input.url").each(function( index ) {
    if ( jsonObj[index].url ) {
      $(this).val( jsonObj[index].url );
  }
});
```

The problems is that if my JSON object has 1 value for "name" but `.each()` finds 2 inputs, once it gets to the second input I get this error in my console.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Then my second .each() function fails to run. What can I do to avoid this issue?

Comment: You need to add a new `item` to `jsonObj` for each subsequent `index` - at the moment `jsonObj[0]` is the only thing with an `item`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure `jsonObj[index]` is defined before trying to get the `name` or `url`.

```
$("input.name").each(function( index ) {
  var data = jsonObj[index];
  if ( data && data.name ) {
    $(this).val( data.name );
  }
});

$("input.url").each(function( index ) {
  var data = jsonObj[index];
  if ( data && data.url ) {
    $(this).val( data.url );
  }
});
```

Comment: You could also add an `} else { return false; }` to stop it from looping through remaining elements on the page if there is no associated data for them

Answer (score 0):

Json objet is in this form::

```
var jsonobj={"name":"1stname","url":"firsturl"};
```

with this format you can execute your code.

and what you are forming is basically an array.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the index is less than the length of the array, otherwise quit the loop:

```
$("input.name").each(function( index ) {
  if (index < jsonObj.length && jsonObj[index].name ) {
    $(this).val( jsonObj[index].name );
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});

$("input.url").each(function( index ) {
  if ( index < jsonObj.length && jsonObj[index].url ) {
    $(this).val( jsonObj[index].name );
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

[Fork](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mBvyC)